# Instant search bar for HTML table with info from MySQL table

Tags: php, html, mysql

So simply put I'm trying to make a simple search engine where I've got a MySQL database and its contents being displayed on a HTML table (using PHP to get the information) and I want to make a search bar that as you type, filters the list automatically.
I've found tutorials on how to make that with plain text where it displays in just a list, but nothing on how to filter an already displayed table.

If someone could point in me in the direction of some helpful links or maybe some  code I could use to start me off that would be great, sorry if this has been answered before, I've been looking for 20 odd minutes and just can't find anything that works.

**TLDR**: Making a search bar that as you type, filters an HTML table filled a with MySQL database table's information brought onto the page via PHP code, cant find any tutorials or helpful links/code after 20-ish min of searching and came here.

Comment: you can use datatable `https://datatables.net/` plugin to achieve your goal.

Comment: @HareshKumar I've tried using that before but I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done with AJAX. You have to use javascript if you want to display it live when the user is typing. Since you want a shoot in the right direction, here is the place to go :
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp

You will need to use SQL to populate the array in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Concept is when you type some javascript trigger a event with the data you typed, like this.

```
$( "input[type='text']" ).change(function() {
  var typedValue =  $( this ).val();

  //AJAX CALL HERE
});
```

Ajax calls a PHP page with the data posted, and use that data in your select Query.

Standard example of [select query](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-where-clause.htm)